# ACTION property and custom actions

Tags: windows-installer

I'm confused with understanding of using [administrative installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367541(v=vs.85).aspx) with custom actions and custom dialogs.

My installation package displays special dialog to accept configuration data from user, and then calls custom action to write this data into configuration file.

As I understand, in this specific situation, the dialog and custom action is to be called only if ACTION=INSTALL. I don't call it when ACTION=ADMIN|ADVERTISE. Is it right?

Comment: A little more details would help. An administrative installation is initiated using msiexec /a  <path to the msi package>. The administrative install isn't installing the product. It's creating an uncompressed installable image. Basically it's expanding the cab files in the existing installer. An administrative installation has its own set of  sequences(AdminExecuteSequence, AdminUISequence) which it executes . You dont have to worry about the dialog being invoked during an administrative installation. Make your dialog part of the InstallUI sequence and things will work as expected.

Comment: Nor do you worry about  using a condition of  ACTION=INSTALL. Just make sure that you include your dialogs as well as the custom action part of the proper sequences. In your case it should be one of  InstallUI or the InstallExecute sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I understood.